# Laravel Queue Error - "The script tried to call a method on an incomplete object"

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I'm encountering an issue in my Laravel application when trying to dispatch a job using Laravel Queue. The error message I'm getting is:

```
Error: The script tried to call a method on an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "App\Jobs\SeedingCustomerData" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide an autoloader to load the class definition in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php:117
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(117): method_exists()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(70): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->dispatchThroughMiddleware()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(98): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(428): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(378): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(172): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(117): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon()
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker()
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call()
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\Container\Container->call()
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(298): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute()
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1040): Illuminate\Console\Command->run()
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(301): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(171): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(94): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\Console\Application->run()
#21 /var/www/html/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
#22 {main}
```

Here's the relevant code in my controller

```
  public function processing_customer_subscription(Request $request)
{
  try {
    $token = $this->generateSeedingToken();
    $customer = Customer::where('email', $request->input('email'))->orWhere('id', $request->input('user_id'))->first();
    if ($customer == null)
      throw new \Exception('data customer tidak ditemukan', 422);

    $module = Module::where('code', $request->input('code_module'))->first();
    $package = Package::where([
      'code' => $request->input('code_package'),
      'module_id' => $module->id
    ])->first();

    $check_sub = CustomerSubscription::where([
      'billing_number' => $request->input('billing_number'),
      'customer_id' => $customer->id
    ])->count();

    if ($check_sub > 0) {
      // TODO
      $subs = CustomerSubscription::where('billing_number', $request->input('billing_number'))->first();
      $this->response['data'] = $subs;
      $this->response['msg']  = 'berhasil';
    } else {
      $db = DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $customer, $module, $package, $token) {
        // create subscription data
        $subs = new CustomerSubscription();
        $subs->id = $this->generateRandomUuid();
        $subs->customer_id = $customer->id;
        $subs->module_id = $module->id;
        $subs->package_id = $package->id;
        $subs->billing_number = $request->input('billing_number');
        $subs->start_date = $request->input('start_date');
        $subs->end_date = $request->input('end_date');
        $subs->max_user = $package->max_user;
        $subs->max_data = $package->max_data;
        $subs->contract_value = $request->input('total_price');
        $subs->payment_status = 'PAID';
        $subs->status = 'ACTIVE';
        $subs->save();

        return $subs;
      });

      SeedingCustomerData::dispatch($customer->code, $token)->afterCommit();
      $this->response['data'] = $db;
      $this->response['msg']  = 'berhasil';
    }

    return $this->response;

  } catch (\Throwable $th) {
    $errorCode = ($th->getCode() > 99 && $th->getCode() < 600) ? $th->getCode() : 500;
    throw new \Exception($th->getMessage(), $errorCode);
  }
}
```

In my job class (SeedingCustomerData):

```
class SeedingCustomerData implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels, Common;
    private $code;
    private $token;

    public function __construct($code, $token)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        set_time_limit(160);
        $customer = Customer::select('id','name','code','email','phone','password')->where('code', $this->code)->first();
       
        $dataToSeed = [
            'charter_categories' => CharterCategory::all(),
            'charter_delivery_statuses' => CharterDeliveryStatus::all(),
            'charter_value_categories' => CharterValueCategory::all(),
            'category_file' => CategoryFile::all(),
            'cost_resources' => CostResource::all(),
            'charter_tags' => CharterTag::all(),
            'charter_type_groups' => CharterGroupType::all(),
            'currencies' => Currency::all(),
            'partners' => Partner::all(),
            'pay_types' => PaymentType::all(),
            'risk_categories' => RiskCategory::all(),
            'risk_impacts' => RiskImpact::all(),
            'risk_statuses' => RiskStatus::all(),
            'stackholder_types' => StackholderType::all()
            // 'Language' => Language::all(),
            // 'Theme' => Theme::all()
        ];

        $dbTenant = DB::connection('tenant_master');

        try {
            $dbTenant->beginTransaction();

            foreach ($dataToSeed as $modelName => $data) {
                $this->seedData($dbTenant, $modelName, $data, $customer->code);
            }

            $dbTenant->commit();

            SeedingStatus::on('pgsql')->where('token', $this->token)
                ->update([
                    'seeding_end_time' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'is_successful' => true,
                ]);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            $dbTenant->rollback();
        }
    }

    private function seedData($db, $modelName, $data, $tenantCode)
    {
        if (count($data) > 0) {
            $data->each(function ($record) use ($db, $modelName, $tenantCode) {
                unset($record->deleted_at);
                unset($record->id);
                $record->tenant_id = $tenantCode;
                $record->id = $this->generateRandomUuid();

                $db->table(strtolower($modelName))->updateOrInsert(
                    ['tenant_id' => $tenantCode],
                    $record->toArray()
                );
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried several things to resolve this issue, including checking if the class is properly autoloaded and ensuring that the necessary dependencies are loaded. However, I'm still stuck with this error.

Can someone please help me understand what might be causing this error and how to fix it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you restart your queue worker after any changes are made to the code. Your queue worker's can't pick up any changes to code until they are restarted. So, if you created this job class, but never restarted the queue worker, the worker won't have any idea this class exists.

Comment: @patricus i always restart my queue worker but still got this error.

Answer (score 0):

**Job Serialization:**

If you are dispatching a job with Eloquent models or custom classes, make sure that
these models are properly serializable. You can check that by ensuring your model
implements the Serializable interface.

```
class MyModel extends Model implements Serializable
{
    // ... Model code ...

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize($this->attributes);
    }

    public function unserialize($data)
    {
        $this->attributes = unserialize($data);
    }
}
```

**Run below command**

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan confing:cache
php artisan confing:clear
php artisan optimize:clear
composer dump autoload
```

To fix this issue, you should ensure that the class definition of Customer and all the other
model classes being used inside the SeedingCustomerData job is available when the job is
unserialized.You can do this by adding these classes to the use statement of your job class
so that Laravel is aware of them when deserializing the job.

Here's how you can modify your SeedingCustomerData job class to include the necessary use statements:

```
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use App\Customer;  // Add the necessary use statement for the Customer model
use App\CharterCategory; // Include use statements for all other models used in the job

class SeedingCustomerData implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels, Common;
    
    // ... Rest of your class code ...

    public function handle()
    {
        // ... Rest of your handle method ...

        $customer = Customer::select('id','name','code','email','phone','password')->where('code', $this->code)->first();
       
        // ... Rest of your handle method ...

        foreach ($dataToSeed as $modelName => $data) {
            $this->seedData($dbTenant, $modelName, $data, $customer->code);
        }

        // ... Rest of your handle method ...
    }

    // ... Rest of your class code ...
}
```

Make sure you've added use statements for all the model classes used in the SeedingCustomerData job.
This will ensure that Laravel can properly unserialize and use these classes within the job.